# How to insert multiple date in DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've some date that I must insert in this control. Each date must be recognized by the user by the color of the day. I want to know how to insert multiple date in DateTimePicker, for example I've:

```
20/07/2015<br>
21/07/2015<br>
22/07/2015<br>
```

And the final result in the DataTimePicker will be:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do multiple dates your best bet is to utilize the [MonthCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class/control, once you spin one up you have a few styles you can assign dates to, for example:

```
this.monthCalendar1.AnnuallyBoldedDates = 
            new System.DateTime[] { new System.DateTime(2015, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    new System.DateTime(2015, 7, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0)};
```

Comment: I doesn't have this control in wpf tool :\

Answer (score 1):

You can add those dates to `SelectedDates` of the control and you can also change the style of selection.

Comment: I don't want selecte a date, I want to save multiple date in the DateTimePicker and colore the saved dates